# Purchase in Android

Tags: android, in-app-billing

I'd like to implement a purchase in Android OS. We'd like to sell digital content through the application.
Is it possible not to use In-app Billing and not to pay 30% to Google?

Comment: Make your own billing? (Unknown if you may in case of licences)

Comment: See http://techcrunch.com/2010/05/19/paypal-launches-in-app-payment-library-for-android/

Comment: NO
you can use paypal, for billing if you don't want to give Google :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're distributing it through the Play Store and the the digital content is only useful within your app, then no.  See [Android Market Developer Program Policies](http://www.android.com/us/developer-content-policy.html#showlanguages).

Comment: No, I'd like to sell music and films-so the user can hear/see it on his mobile phone. So can I use PayPall?